# eclipse annoyances: Debug and Launch toolbars unavailable

Tags: eclipse, debugging, launch, toolbars

I am running Windows XP and Eclipse 4.2.2 Build id: M20130204-1200 and I have lost my Debug and Launch tool bars. I have tried Windows>Reset Perspective  (original values) and  Window>Customize Perspective's (Tool Bar Visibility and Command Groups Availability) tab options. I have tried the Layout option on Debug view. All failed to bring them back. Right now, I am looking at Tool Bar Visibility tab and  a message that says: <"Debug" cannot be made available because it is in the unavailable "null" command group.> However, the Debug checkbox in Command Group Availability is checked.

I have also tried right-click and Reset on the perspective buttons.
Switching to another eclipse installation (same machine) did not help either.

Rebooting does not help.

Are there any text configuration files  where this data is stored that can be manipulated outside eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in Eclipse Kepler, it turns out it was caused by PyDev plugin. I fixed it by uninstalling the plugin and right-clicking on the Debug perspective button and selecting Reset.

Answer (score 1):

I had already installed a fresh copy and the problems persisted. But, encouraged by user714965 comments, I tried again but that did not resolve the issue. Then, I threw away all eclipse installation folders (to recycle bin), re-installed fresh copy, and the problem persisted. Then I started a new workspace, and it seemed like the tool bars were back. Then restored previous eclipse installations and they had the Debug toolbar as well!

I am thinking somehow the customization config files were broken. It would be nice to know where the these files are stored (my original question): Are they global for each user on the machine or are they workspace specific?  It seems to me that some customizations are global, while others are project specific.

May be it is time to try the new Android Studio :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems as your eclipse is broken. The fastest way to get it back running will be downloading a fresh copy from [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). You can continue using your current workspace so your settings will remain. But you have to re-install all plug-ins... I'm always keeping a backup of a fresh release with the plug-ins I'm using. I would suggest you to do the same in the future.

Comment: Not related to this question,but can you give a list of your plugins for reference?